# Modifying data to be marshalled to JSON

Tags: go

I have code where I am pulling out data from mongo & would like to give it out as an API response. My main challenge is not being able to transform data before pushing it out.

```
var result interface{}

respBody, err := json.Marshal(result)
```

Is it possible to edit marshalled result before it goes out? eg. Take out some fields?

Comment: Yes, just have a look at examples for `json.Marshal()`. Your example, as it is, will produce an empty json object.

Comment: Why don't you take out *those* fields before `json.Marshal()`.

Comment: Your code doesn't show the result "going out" - you've just marshalled it into a byte slice. You can do whatever you want with that byte slice before sending it as a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common way to accomplish what you described you're trying would be something like this:

```
type Data struct {
    Name    string
    Age     int
    Address *Address
    // more fields of your data object
}

type Response struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
}

func GetResponse(d Data) ([]byte, error) {
    r := Response{
        Name: d.Name,
        Age:  d.Age,
        // anything else
    }

    return json.Marshal(r)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that shed some light.  I can even combine  I guess those two in theory.  My struggle was to be able to change the field names.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove some fields from json response, then you can do as below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type User struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Password string `json:"-"` . //remove from json
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    u := &User{Name:"alpha", Password: "beta"}
    b, _ := json.Marshal(u)
    fmt.Println(string(b))

}
```

For some use cases, you can also have custom json Marshaller by implementing the 
`MarshalJSON` on User struct.
For example to change field names:

```
func (u *User) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(&struct {
        Name string `json:"name"`
        Key string `json:"key"`
    }{
        Name: u.Name,
        Key: u.Password,
    })
}
```